# Jvm comes with JDk or it default comes with os

Tags: java

I have a confusion of JVM. does it comes with os or JDK ,because I have read in many books ,it comes with JDK but JVM is not plat form independent it means that it comes with the os .Can any one clear my doubt?

Comment: No JVM is not included with the OS. You have to install JRE to get JVM. Please refer [Wikipedia Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine).

Answer (score 3):

Think of the JVM / JRE / JDK as a car:

The JVM (Java Virtual Machine) is the engine of the car. It's the essential part that makes the car run. Likewise with Java, the JVM is the engine that can run Java bytecode. It's the interface between Java bytecode and the operating system and hardware of the computer.

The JRE (Java Runtime Environment) is the rest of the car. To be able to drive a car, you need more than just the engine (the JVM). You need a chassis, wheels, a steering wheel, pedals, etc. The JRE provides everything around the JVM, such as libraries and tools needed to run Java programs.

The JDK (Java Development Kit) provides extra tools on top of the JRE that you need when you want to write your own Java programs. It contains the Java compiler and other tools that you need to create Java class files from source code.

On Oracle's website, you can download either the JRE or the JDK.

If you are an end user and you just need to run Java programs that other people have created for you, then the JRE is all you need. It's a complete car - it includes the JVM (the engine of the car).

If you are a programmer and you want to write your own Java programs, then you need the JDK. Oracle's JDK package includes the JVM and JRE, as well as the Java compiler and other development tools.

The JVM is provided by Oracle (or by another party, if you are using a different Java implementation than Oracle's). It is not normally included with the operating system.